# How to deploy a web app with static files in docker?

Tags: docker, go, templates, static, containers

I built a web app with [echo](https://echo.labstack.com/). Some source in `server.go` is

```
package main

import ...

type TemplateRenderer struct {
    templates *template.Template
}

func (t *TemplateRenderer) Render(w io.Writer, name string, data interface{}, c echo.Context) error {
    if viewContext, isMap := data.(map[string]interface{}); isMap {
        viewContext["reverse"] = c.Echo().Reverse
    }

    return t.templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, name, data)
}

func main() {
    e := echo.New()
    e.Static("/static", "static")

    renderer := &TemplateRenderer{
        templates: template.Must(template.ParseGlob("public/views/*.html")),
    }
    e.Renderer = renderer

    e.GET("/", func(c echo.Context) error {
        return c.Render(http.StatusOK, "index.html", map[string]interface{}{})
    })

    e.Logger.Fatal(e.Start(":8080"))
}
```

Project tree

```
├── helper
│   └── string.go
└─── site
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── go.mod
    ├── go.sum
    ├── server.go
    ├── public
    │   └── views
    │       └── index.html
    └── static
```

I can run `go run server.go` to start server, everything works well. But got error if run it with docker.

Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.15.2-alpine3.12 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
WORKDIR /app/site
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o server

FROM alpine:3.12
COPY --from=builder /app/site /bin/.
ENTRYPOINT [ "server" ]
```

Built a docker image by

```
docker build -t gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/myapp -f site/Dockerfile .
```

Run app in docker

```
docker run --rm -p 8080:8080 gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/myapp
panic: html/template: pattern matches no files: `public/views/*.html`

goroutine 1 [running]:
html/template.Must(...)
    /usr/local/go/src/html/template/template.go:372
main.main()
    /app/site/server.go:76 +0x2af
```

It seems the `public` folder didn't been copied into image. But there wasn't any error when built the image. What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you are using a [multi-stage Docker build](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) which is perfect for only copying the compiled binary to the final image. In your Dockerfile, however, you are copying the entire build directory - the binary `server` as well as all the source.

Secondly, your main problem is when the image is run as a container, the default work directory is `/` - and thus any paths within your server are not find the html files in `/bin/public`.

If you ever need to debug a docker image - especially if it is an image based on a linux distro like alpine- simply:

```
docker run -it myimage /bin/sh
```

Anyway the 2 simple fixes to your docker:

```
FROM golang:1.15.2-alpine3.12 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
WORKDIR /app/site
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o server

FROM alpine:3.12
COPY --from=builder /app/site/server /bin
COPY --from=builder /app/site/public /public
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/server" ]
```

Comment: As the container can't start so can't debug it with sh method. Your solution resolved my problem.Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you providing the exact docker tag of your image you built? Passing `/bin/sh` should work - even if your regular entry point is failing.

Comment: Yes, I tried it. But it got the same error as before - the panic error. I don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

In Go 1.16 you can compile these files into the binary itself.  So you'll need to upgrade the Go toolchain on your host system, and also the `FROM` line in your build stage in the Dockerfile.  Go 1.16 adds the [`embed`](https://golang.org/pkg/embed/) package and a new `//go:embed` directive to support this.

First, you need to tell the compiler to embed the template files, building a filesystem object:

```go
import "embed"

// templateFiles contains the raw text of the template files.
//go:embed public/views/*.html
var templateFiles embed.FS
```

Then, when you go to use it, Go 1.16 also adds a corresponding [`("html/template").ParseFS`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#ParseFS) function:

```go
renderer := &TemplateRenderer{
    templates: template.Must(template.ParseFS(templateFiles)),
}
```

Now all of the files are embedded in the binary itself, and you shouldn't get "file not found" type errors.  You might consider copying only the compiled binary and not anything else into the final image.

```sh
# Upgrade to Go 1.16
FROM golang:1.16-alpine3.12 AS builder
# Unchanged from original
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
WORKDIR /app/site
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o server

FROM alpine:3.12
# Only copy the compiled binary and not the source tree
COPY --from=builder /app/site/server /bin
# Generally prefer CMD to ENTRYPOINT
CMD [ "server" ]
```

Comment: I heard embedding was coming at some pt. Nice!